# Add UINavigation Bar with Code and make constraints with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

I add Navigation Bar with code in UICollectionView. Here is the code.

```
let height: CGFloat = 65
let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: height))
```

It works well. But when I rotate the screen, the navigation Bar width appears only half of the screen. I would like to make the full screen width. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try 
`let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width` and now use bounds for the width of the navigation bar.

Comment: I tried it. But, not work when rotate . Thanks @AnuraagDJain

Comment: I think on rotate you need to set the frame of navigation bar again to adjust the screen's width.

Comment: How to do it bro?

Comment: navbar.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]

try this thing first.

Comment: Bro @AnuraagDJain, your codes work !!! Thank you very much bro. :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Kudos :)